# How to print an array inside other array but without "0" index?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, parameters

stack Community, I have an array called $gallery[] with his keys and values and i have to insert it to another array called $params[]

```
$gallery = [
    "image_1": "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12331231.jpg",
    "image_2": "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12312312.jpg",
];

$params = [
            "codpro" => $props[0]->codpro,
            "city_code" => $props[0]->city_code,
            "address" => $props[0]->address,
            "latitude" => $props[0]->latitude,
            "longitude" => $props[0]->longitude,
            $gallery
        ];

return $params;
```

After i return $params have this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "image_1": "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12331231.jpg",
    "image_2": "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12312312.jpg",
  },
  "codpro": 5354055,
  "city_code": null,
  "address": "Calle 47 A # 45 A 31",
  "latitude": "3.5426742",
  "longitude": "-76.3173984",
  
}
```

But i need something like this:

```
{
  "image_1": "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12331231.jpg",
  "image_2": "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12312312.jpg",
  "codpro": 5354055,
  "city_code": null,
  "address": "Calle 47 A # 45 A 31",
  "latitude": "3.5426742",
  "longitude": "-76.3173984",
  
}
```

Comment: use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php:
array_merge($gallery, $params)

Comment: Or even `array1 + array2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *array_merge()* php function to get the results. Save the following code in a file, call it array_merge.php and try it in a browser. It should give you your desired results.

```
<?php

$gallery = [
    "image_1"=> "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12331231.jpg",
    "image_2"=> "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12312312.jpg",
];

$params = [
            "codpro" => "props[0]->codpro",
            "city_code" => "props[0]->city_code",
            "address" => "props[0]->address",
            "latitude" => "props[0]->latitude",
            "longitude" => "props[0]->longitude",
        ];


//return $params;
print_r(array_merge($gallery, $params));

?>
```

Here are the results when viewed in a browser

```
Array
(
    [image_1] => https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12331231.jpg
    [image_2] => https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12312312.jpg
    [codpro] => props[0]->codpro
    [city_code] => props[0]->city_code
    [address] => props[0]->address
    [latitude] => props[0]->latitude
    [longitude] => props[0]->longitude
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$params['gallery'] = $gallery;
```

Your $gallery variable also has error in it. It should be like this:

```
$gallery = [
    "image_1" => "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12331231.jpg",
    "image_2" => "https://staticw.s3.amazonaws.com/object/12312312.jpg"
];
```

Comment: That´s make have another question, Thanks. My $gallery variable was filled with this: foreach ($images as $key => $value) {
            $key_number = $key + 1;
            $gallery["image_$key_number"] = 
            $value["imageurl"];
}

Comment: It´s wrong made this?

Comment: @EstebanSuarez you should use foreach($images as $key => $value) only if you need value of key or if it does not matter which value comes up first. You can use for loop also to do the same thing. It would go like this

for($counter = 0; $counter < count($gallery); $counter++) {
   
}

And you could just use this $counter in the same way as you use $key variable. You should not also use string with variable as key. Instead of that you should do it like this:

$selector = 'image_' . $key_number;
$gallery[$selector} = $value['imageurl'];